# Sharepoint backup permissions

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, sql-server, backup

When I run a Sharepoint farm backup, I get an error `Object SharePoint_2013_Config failed in event OnBackup. For more information, see the spbackup.log or sprestore.log file located in the backup directory. 
    SqlException: Cannot open backup device '\\***\SharepointBackup\Full\spbr0002\000000A5.bak'. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.). 
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.`

When looking at this [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20732.sharepoint-2010-cannot-open-backup-device-f-foldername-operating-system-error-5-access-is-denied.aspx), I see that I need to give permissions specifically to the user account running SQL server. However, when I look at the service login account, it says `NTSERVICE\MSSQL$SQL`.

When I research that user account ([link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9e6bb2de-8fd0-45de-ab02-d59bbe05f72e/servicedatabase-accounts-nt-servicemssqlserver-nt-servicesqlserveragent-what-are-they-for?forum=sqlsecurity.)), I find that user account is unusable by anything besides services, and when I search for that account to configure permissions for my backup folder, i can't find it.

One thing I saw was to enable the proxy account on the SQL server. I did that (Object explorer>SQL instance (rt. click)>properties security), but that didn't seem to make a difference.
Any help is appreciated